# How can I stop cin >> with just enter without typing words in C++?

Tags: c++

Why does cin keep prompting even if I hit enter?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name = "";
    cout << "What's your name?";
    cin  >> name;

    cout << "Hello "";
    if (name == "")
       cout << "World!";
    else
       cout << name + "!";
    return 0;
}
```

I want cin >> to stop when I hit enter without typing any words so if the user enters nothing it will show a default Hollow World message and otherwise customized message.

Comment: What is `String`?

Comment: Oh it's typo. It's just string

Comment: @Jay, please edit your question and fix the typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >> name;`keeps reading until you've entered something. You want a function that just reads a single line. That function is called `getline`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name = "";
    cout << "What's your name?";
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "Hello "";
    if (name == ""){
       cout << "World!";
    else
       cout << name + "!";
    return 0;
}
```